# Angular ngx-mat-datetime-picker selected Event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

i'm using ngx-mat-datetime-picker. is there any way to detect changes when user change the date. or to get the new selected date ?
[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where's your starting point in code? Next to that, the library is deprecated.